# How to Store Data To Show at Chart using Java?

Tags: java, charts, in-memory-database

I have a Spring based Java application. I have two types of data.

**First one** is indexed document number at my application. Documents are indexed only 2 or 3 times a week.

**Second one** is number of searches. Many users searches something at my application. I want to visualize the search terms. Many data flows at any time.

What do you suggest me to store such kind of data using Java?

For first one I think that I can use RRD or something like that or I can even write data into a table at MySQL etc.

For second one I can use a more sophisticated database and I can use an in memory database as like H2 between my sophisticated database and user interface.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [Redis](http://redis.io/)? It has great support for atomic increments if you wanted to track search counts and its also very fast since data is stored in-memory.